# Adding additional styles to the Style section in a List View Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

If I add a List View Web Part on a page and edit the current view there is a section under "Totals" called "Style". Is there a way to add a custom style in this list so the user can select it? The custom style will be applied to the list view web part changing the background colors of the rows and headers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not done it myself, throwing some links that may set the direction for you:

[Why is changing on VWSTYLES.XML file not taking effect when I run iisreset?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16692/why-is-changing-on-vwstyles-xml-file-not-taking-effect-when-i-run-iisreset)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/5db758b0-c584-4911-96d3-94838574a5d0